# bash How to get html code from links in txt file

Tags: bash

I have a text document that contains  URL's was write in the same way:

https://google.com

https://youtube.com

This code should read strings and get the html status from each strings in file. So it can't find the URL, i guess

```
exec 0<$1  #(Where $1 is param to input the file)
while IFS='' read -r line 
response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null $line)
[[ -n "$line" ]]
do
echo "Text read from file: $line"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code save as the HtmlStatus.sh
you can create file for example test.txt
 
text.txt : https://google.com
           https://youtube.com
           https://facebook.com

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do 
    echo -n "Read Url : $line"
    curl -I $line | grep HTTP

done < "$1"
```

this code return the html status code at the test.txt file line in url.
run terminal :

```
chmod +x HtmlStatus.sh
./HtmlStatus.sh test.txt
```